# I get a timeout when I try to install Android app through Eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse, vmware, readonly, ubuntu-8.04

Whenever I try to install an Android app on my HTC device via the Eclipse ADT I get:

```
[2010-07-27 15:33:20 - Touch] Failed to upload Touch.apk on device '<MyHTC serialNo>'
[2010-07-27 15:33:20 - Touch] java.io.IOException: Unable to upload file: timeout
[2010-07-27 15:33:20 - Touch] Launch canceled!
```

I am running on Ubuntu 8.04 in vmware (on a Vista system).

When I type 'adb devices' my HTC shows up perfectly.
When I type 'adb pull system ..' the whole content of the system directory on my HTC gets copied to my Ubuntu machine.
When I try 'adb push bla' I get `failed to copy 'bla' to '<MyHTC serialNo>': Read-only file system`
When I try 'adb remount' I get `remount failed: Operation not permitted`

I have a feeling the problem of the Eclipse (6 sec) timeout is caused because my HTC is read-only. Installing on the emulator works fine.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is caused because of the read-only status on the HTC you have plugged in. I assume you have tried this before and succeeded?

To make ADB work with Windows 7, download HTC Sync from the HTC Website, it has the drivers for the droid eris and ADB Drivers for Windows 7. http://member.america.htc.com/download/Driver/DROID_ERIS_Verizon/HTCSync2.0.25.zip